# Add a div below inline-block wrapped row

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, css-position

I have a list of inline-block elements that wrap to form several rows. I'd like to display a div element between on of the rows, depending on where a specific element is located. For example, the first few rows are numbered:

[image: numbered inline-block elements]

If I wanted to target the third element and display a full length element (100% of the div containing the blocks), then it would look like this:

[image: between first and second rows]

The position of the full-length div would be the same for any of the blocks 1-5. Or, if another block was targeted, like 7 or 8, it would look like:

[image: between second and third rows]

Notice how the rows are "shifted down". I understand how to do this with block-level elements, but not in between rows of wrapped inline-block elements. The rows that each of the numbered blocks would be on would change as the browser window width changes, and the full-length div would "know" which row to be positioned beneath.

How would someone go about placing the div below that particular row of elements? Is it possible with some kind of relative or absolute position with CSS? Could the row position change dynamically as the blocks are reordered with window width changes?

**UPDATE:**
Here is a [codepen](http://cdpn.io/AiIzf) that has the blocks and the inserted div. The div is styled to be absolutely positioned, and can be moved to the appropriate position by inserting it after the desired block element tag, but I still can't get the row beneath it to make room and slide down.

Comment: And what's your HTML?

Comment: show us some code, or even a fiddle we can play with...

Comment: I assume that the full-width block would be either inserted with JavaScript or the display property toggled accordingly? So for a proof-of-concept, if we can achieve with CSS something like your 2nd figure, we are good?

Comment: @DavidThomas et al I added a codepen so you can get your hands on some code.

Comment: @Marc Audet Yes, the second figure is the goal. The div can be moved before or after any element of the blocks with JS/jQ, so that's not an issue ... it's the making space underneath the div. See the codepen.

Comment: I think you need a jQuery plug-in like Manonry or Packery or isotope  This problem requires a JavaScript aided solution.  As the efforts below show, it is not that easy to write a bullet-proof code.  However, someone may come along with an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a different alternative:

http://jsfiddle.net/SYJaj/7/

There is no need to have the "banner" be absolutely positioned. Just give it `display:inline-block;` like everything else, and calculate which block it needs to follow with the `offset` method in jQuery.

The key is in this code:

```
function placeAfter($block) {
    $block.after($('#content'));
}

$('.wrapblock').click(function() {
    $('#content').css('display','inline-block');
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    var $blocks = $(this).nextAll('.wrapblock');
    if ($blocks.length == 0) {
        placeAfter($(this));
        return false;
    }
    $blocks.each(function(i, j) {
        if($(this).offset().top != top) {
            placeAfter($(this).prev('.wrapblock'));
            return false;
        } else if ((i + 1) == $blocks.length) {
            placeAfter($(this));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: Changed the stylesheet to look like yours.

Comment: This is close... the tricky bit is getting the little squares to leap over the wide block... +1 for a good start!

Comment: Ideally, as you resize the window, the squares should wrap around the wide div instead of forming a second row or leaving white space on the right.

Comment: This works in Chrome...what are you seeing? Or are you talking about on resize?

Comment: Yes, on resize, it needs to reflow the squares.

Comment: I added a $(window).on('resize') piece to the code. Anything else I'm not catching?

Comment: This looks good.  There are design options in how to handle the extreme cases, for example, if the layout shrinks to one column, where does the content block go, beneath the cell that was clicked or the row that was clicked?  However, you need some feedback from the OP before doing any more work! Well done!

Comment: Thanks! I'm still pretty new here so it's nice to have the feedback.

Comment: @AlexMorrise Great solution! The resize works great in Chrome, FF, Safari. It seems that when the layout is shrunk to one column, the content goes where it should (i.e. the cell and the row are the same).

Answer (score 2):

Challenge accepted. A CSS only solution:

http://codepen.io/mlhaufe/pen/aONRGP

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <label class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="rdo-visible">
        <span class="box">1</span>
        <span class="block">1. Lipsum Lipsum</span>
    </label>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    width: 60%;
    margin:auto;
    font: 16pt sans-serif;
}
.item {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}
[name=rdo-visible] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
[name=rdo-visible]:checked ~ .box {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
[name=rdo-visible]:checked ~ .block {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1.6em;
}
.box {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.block {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Very creative! I like the use of just HTML and CSS without JS.