# Remove the need for a second .click within a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a similar set up to a similar question where I have a row of inline-blocks which on click of any of the blocks creates a content box beneath that row.

[Add a div below inline-block wrapped row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096011/add-a-div-below-inline-block-wrapped-row)

The difference being is that on click of a block I have data loaded via AJAX, using the fiddle provided on the linked question I have the function working except for the fact I must press the block twice in order to run both functions.

The 1st Click: Loads the data VIA AJAX

The 2nd Click: Creates the Content Box beneath row of blocks

If you take a look at my code below you can see the comment "THIS ON CLICK BELOW IS THE EVENT I AM TRYING TO REMOVE"

You can see there is a duplicate of the "gameListing Click Event", basically I am trying to link this to the first Click Event so I only need to click once.

I hope this makes sense, I am happy to expand my question if needs be.

```
// -------------- MAIN CLICK FUNCTION --------------
$('.gameListing').click(function(){

    $('.gameListing').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    call_ajax(url);
});


// -------------- GET PREV / NEXT ITEMS --------------
$('.prev').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.gameListing.active');
    $current.removeClass('active')
    var postNumber = parseInt($current.attr('data-count'));
    var nextPost = (postNumber - 1);
    $("[data-count='"+nextPost+"']").trigger("click");
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.gameListing.active');
    $current.removeClass('active')
    var postNumber = parseInt($current.attr('data-count'));
    var nextPost = (postNumber + 1);
    $("[data-count='"+nextPost+"']").trigger("click");
});


// -------------- MAIN AJAX FUNCTION CALL --------------
function call_ajax(url) {

    $.ajax( {
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            data: {json:  1},
            dataType: "JSON"
     })

        .done(function( data ) {

        // LOAD GAME INFORMATION
        $("#game-name").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-reels").html(data.post.custom_fields.reels);
        $("#game-paylines").html(data.post.custom_fields.paylines);
        $("#game-minBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.min_bet);
        $("#game-maxBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.max_bet);
        $("#game-jackpot").html(data.post.custom_fields.jackpot);
        $("#game-info").html(data.post.custom_fields.game_info);

        // LOAD GAME PROVIDERS
        var provSource = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
                provSource = provSource.replace(/ /g,"-");
                $("#game_provs").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + provSource + "/ .gameBox-Ops");

        // LOAD GAME THUMBNALS
        var gameThumbSrc = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
        gameThumbSrc = gameThumbSrc.replace(/ /g,'');

        $('#gameBoxGallery').html('');
            for(i = 0;  i<= 2; i++){
                            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-' + i + '.jpg" class="gameThumb">'
                            $('#gameBoxGallery').append(image);
        };

        // ZOOM FIRST THUMBNAIL
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').html('');
            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-0' + '.jpg" id="gameScreenshot">'
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').append(image);

        })  



// -------------- CREATE CONTENT BOX  --------------

        function placeAfter($block) {
            $block.after($('#gameBox'));
        }

        var $chosen = null;


        // -------------- THIS ON CLICK BELOW IS THE EVENT I AM TRYING TO REMOVE --------------
        $('.gameListing').on('click', function() {


            $chosen = $(this);
            $('#gameBox').css('display','inline-block');
            $('#gameBox').slideDown( 3000 );


            var top = $(this).offset().top;
            var $blocks = $(this).nextAll('.gameListing');
            if ($blocks.length == 0) {
                placeAfter($(this));
                return false;
            }
            $blocks.each(function(i, j) {
                if($(this).offset().top != top) {
                    placeAfter($(this).prev('.gameListing'));
                    return false;
                } else if ((i + 1) == $blocks.length) {
                    placeAfter($(this));
                    return false;
                }
         });

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 40}, 600);
});
}
```

Here is a link to original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SYJaj/7/

Comment: first .. i don't understand why you have jquery.event.on in call_ajax function if you use .on listener

Comment: please forgive any rookie mistakes, I am learning as I go

Comment: iam only asking because i don't understand :) If you .on fnc put outside from call_ajax nothing happend?

Comment: after .done you are missing ; | beware $ it is jquery thing .. remove $ from fnc placeAfter, because you pass object and working with this object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can move the box-appending functionality out of a new click handler and out of the `call_ajax` function. So I did that and made it so that that function is invoked when your AJAX call is done. Since you need `this` (the clicked element), you need to pass that around, too.

You were setting a new click handler inside of the click handler, so that's why your issue was happening.

Without re-structuring your code much I did this...

**Try it:**

```
// -------------- MAIN CLICK FUNCTION --------------
$('.gameListing').click(function () {

    $('.gameListing').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    // Pass the url and the clicked element
    call_ajax(url, this);
});


// -------------- GET PREV / NEXT ITEMS --------------
$('.prev').click(function () {
    var $current = $('.gameListing.active');
    $current.removeClass('active')
    var postNumber = parseInt($current.attr('data-count'));
    var nextPost = (postNumber - 1);
    $("[data-count='" + nextPost + "']").trigger("click");
});

$('.next').click(function () {
    var $current = $('.gameListing.active');
    $current.removeClass('active')
    var postNumber = parseInt($current.attr('data-count'));
    var nextPost = (postNumber + 1);
    $("[data-count='" + nextPost + "']").trigger("click");
});


// -------------- MAIN AJAX FUNCTION CALL --------------
function call_ajax(url, elem) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            json: 1
        },
        dataType: "JSON"
    })
    .done(function (data) {

        // Append the box
        appendBox(elem);

        // LOAD GAME INFORMATION
        $("#game-name").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-reels").html(data.post.custom_fields.reels);
        $("#game-paylines").html(data.post.custom_fields.paylines);
        $("#game-minBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.min_bet);
        $("#game-maxBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.max_bet);
        $("#game-jackpot").html(data.post.custom_fields.jackpot);
        $("#game-info").html(data.post.custom_fields.game_info);

        // LOAD GAME PROVIDERS
        var provSource = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
        provSource = provSource.replace(/ /g, "-");
        $("#game_provs").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + provSource + "/ .gameBox-Ops");

        // LOAD GAME THUMBNALS
        var gameThumbSrc = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
        gameThumbSrc = gameThumbSrc.replace(/ /g, '');

        $('#gameBoxGallery').html('');
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('
            template_directory '); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-' + i + '.jpg" class="gameThumb">'
            $('#gameBoxGallery').append(image);
        };

        // ZOOM FIRST THUMBNAIL
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').html('');
        image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('
        template_directory '); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-0' + '.jpg" id="gameScreenshot">'
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').append(image);

    });
}

// Move the box-appending code outside of the AJAX call,
// and outside of a new click event
function appendBox(elem) {
    var $chosen = $(elem),
        $gameBox = $('#gameBox'),
        top = $chosen.offset().top,
        $blocks = $chosen.nextAll('.gameListing');
    if($chosen.attr('data-id') === $gameBox.attr('data-id')) {
        $gameBox.stop().slideUp(3000, function () {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        });
        $gameBox.attr('data-id', '');
    } else {
        $gameBox.slideDown(3000, function () {
            $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
        });
        $gameBox.attr('data-id', $chosen.attr('data-id'));
    }
    function placeAfter($block) {
        $block.after($gameBox);
    }
    if ($blocks.length == 0) {
        placeAfter($chosen);
        return false;
    }

    $blocks.each(function (i, j) {
        if ($(this).offset().top != top) {
            placeAfter($(this).prev('.gameListing'));
            return false;
        } else if ((i + 1) == $blocks.length) {
            placeAfter($(this));
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $chosen.offset().top - 40
    }, 600);
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, exactly what I was looking to achieve. However the ajax content isn't loaded...

Comment: Hmm, so you click the element, the box appends but the content in the box isn't updated? Check the code inside of the `done` function, and log `data` to see if you got anything. Also, open your web console and see if any errors come up.

Comment: The only error that appears in Console is 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: Ok so I removed the 

   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 40
    }, 600);

And things seem to be working now

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, that should be `scrollTop: $chosen.offset().top - 40`

Comment: Thank you so much for this, cannot stress how helpful it has been. 

My next goal was to detect the Open/Closed state of the GameBox and be able to close it again on a second click, any advice on this?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. Well, take a look at the update, inside of the `appendBox` function. The idea is that when you click on a box, you give the `gameBox` the `data-id` of the clicked box. If the `gameBox` already has that id (which means you already clicked on it), then you hide it, else, you give it the id.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, however the update you provided just loops the slideDown. I would like to provide a fiddle but with everything being pulled with wordpress, ajax and json it is a little difficult.

Comment: Ah, I had tested that on a jsFiddle that didn't have the `slideDown` animation, should work better now. You can play around with the animations (decide when they end, end them abruptly, etc), especially since you're sliding at 3 second intervals. I updated the post, and check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SYJaj/96/ (only works with box 1 and 2, because I only added a `data-id` to those). Don't worry about the jsFiddle, I'm just trying to add stuff to your code based on the fact that it is pretty similar to the jsFiddle you already provided (at least the box bit).

Comment: Hey @Alfonso Garnett, Iv tried to move this discussion to chat but do not have enough rep. Would like your advice on creating creating duplicate "gameboxes" for each prev and next. With the idea being you slide left and right to the next or prev Gamebox. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure, I'd be glad to help, I've made [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77363/room) room, I don't know at what time you are on, though, perhaps it'd be better if you open a new question. I'm sorry for the delay, I've been a bit busy with stuff, just being able to browse stack a bit.