# Add a div below inline-block wrapped row - Part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A solution suggested by @musicnothing in an older [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096011/add-a-div-below-inline-block-wrapped-row) displays a content div below the row of inline divs, this works good when the `div.wrapblock` is clicked itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/SYJaj/7/

```
function placeAfter($block) {
    $block.after($('#content'));
}

$('.wrapblock').click(function() {
    $('#content').css('display','inline-block');
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    var $blocks = $(this).nextAll('.wrapblock');
    if ($blocks.length == 0) {
        placeAfter($(this));
        return false;
    }
    $blocks.each(function(i, j) {
        if($(this).offset().top != top) {
            placeAfter($(this).prev('.wrapblock'));
            return false;
        } else if ((i + 1) == $blocks.length) {
            placeAfter($(this));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having.
I need to trigger the same effect, but by adding the click event to a link within the wrapblock itself.

My code is nearly identical.

What I have changed is the click event handle, from `$('.wrapblock').click(function()` to `$('.more').on('click', function()` I also needed to add  `.closest(".wrapblock")` for the content div to position itself outside of the wrapblock.

```
$('.more').on('click', function() {
...
if ($blocks.length == 0) {
        placeAfter($(this).closest(".wrapblock"));
        return false;
    }
```

Everything can be seen and tested http://jsfiddle.net/7Lt1hnaL/

Would be great if somebody could shed some light on how I can calculate which block it needs to follow with the offset method, thanks in advance.

As you can see in the latest fiddle example, the content div is not displaying below the row of divs.

*I also apologise, I wanted to post on the thread in discussion but I only have a minor posting reputation which doesn't let me, thanks.*

Comment: If you want it to be after all the wrapblocks, why are you moving it to be right after the one that's clicked?  Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: This is the problem. Instead of coming straight after the one that is clicked, I need to calculate and show after the last div in that row. So when clicking 1 for example, it should display after 3. If I click 5, it should display after 6 and so on based on 3 divs per row. As it works in the first fiddle at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $chosen = null;
var $allBlocks = [];
$(function(){
 $allBlocks = $('.wrapblock');
})

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($chosen != null) {
        $('#content').css('display','none');
        $('body').append($('#content'));
        $chosen.trigger('click');   
    }
});

$('.more').on('click', function() {
    $chosen = $(this);
    var position = $chosen.parent('.wrapblock').position();
    $('#content').css('display','inline-block');
    $allBlocks.filter(function(idx, ele){
     return $(ele).position().top == position.top;
    })
    .last()
    .after($('#content'));
});
```

```css
.wrapblock
{
    background: #963a3a;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;
}

#content
{
    display:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
    background: #5582c1;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.more {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    right:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapblock">1
<span class="more" data-ref="1">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">2
<span class="more" data-ref="2">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">3
<span class="more" data-ref="3">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">4
<span class="more" data-ref="4">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">5
<span class="more" data-ref="5">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">6
<span class="more" data-ref="6">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">7
<span class="more" data-ref="7">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">8
<span class="more" data-ref="8">more</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapblock">9
<span class="more" data-ref="9">more</span>
</div>
<div id="content">Some Content</div>
```

Seems to do what you want.  Basically, it just filters down the set of all blocks to the row of the block you clicked on using the assumption that they'll all have the same vertical offset (top), then takes the last one, because jQuery will keep them in document order, so that'll be the last one in the layout row.

Oh, and I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Lt1hnaL/1/

Comment: Don't believe it :) Been working on this for the past 2 days, thanks a lot! This is perfect. Works exactly how it should. As I'm sure you've noticed, this also works in a responsive manner. And thanks for the detailed information so everybody can understand how this works.

Comment: @computerbarry no problem, though you might consider throttling your onresize calls by checking to see if the scroll width didn't change.  If you want to go really nuts with it, you could pre-calculate the width(s) that would cause re-flow and detect that.

Comment: Everything was going well until I tried adding this into the CMS this morning. I keep getting the error _Cannot read property 'top' of undefined_ which points to this peice of code `return $(ele).position().top == position.top;` Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @computerbarry one of the selectors came back empty, so when you call `position()` it returns undefined.  My guess is it's `$chosen.parent('.wrapblock')` because IIRC `.parent()` didn't take a selector filter argument in an old version of jQuery.  Set a breakpoint in the filter callback or add `console.log($(ele).position(), position);` above the return line to see what's what.

Comment: Thanks @dtanders, share the knowledge :) Ok, I've added the console.log as suggested, which returns `Object { top: 0, left: 0 } undefined` I've had problems before with this CMS build, lots of code conflicting. What do you suggest from above? jQuery issue, something else?

Comment: I've just added a breakpoint which returns `<div.flexInner.column__4 mediumColumn__10>` FYI in the production version `.column__4` replaces `.wrapblock`.

Comment: Further information if this helps @dtanders. I have `jquery/2.1.2` and if I `console.log(position)` it returns `undefined`. I've been trying all different combinations inside `$chosen.parent('.wrapblock')` with no luck, everything stays the same. Tricky one, any ideas?

Comment: I fixed it :) I changed `$chosen.parent('.wrapblock')` to `$chosen.closest('.wrapblock')`. Hopefully this will casue no more issues, thanks.

Comment: @computerbarry cool, glad you figured it out and sorry for ghosting you - work comes first, you know?

Comment: Absolutely, I'm in th office right now :) Thanks again anyhow, and been using the inspector a little more, setting breakpoints etc. Enjoy the weekend!